# Statistics of users using different versions of iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios-frameworks

I'm developing a 3p framework in iOS.I'm confused whether to support from iOS5 or iOS6.Can anyone provide me the statistics of how many users still have iOS5?.If almost all the users migrated to iOS6,I can make my framework to support from iOS6 onwards.Thanks.

Comment: @NitinGohel : IS there any data provided by apple,about number of users migration from iOS5?

Comment: before iOS7 was introduced, iOS6 has about 90% of share vs. all other iOSs if I remember correctly. And I've just heard from somewhere that now more than 80% of users have installed iOS7 on their devices.

Comment: @NitinGohel I was just talking about news, sorry if that was not appropriate as a comment. I was in WWDC2013 last year, and the keynote from Tim showed us that iOS6 dominated other iOSs at the time by 90%. And you can also check here: https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/ to see how iOS7 is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has up to date statistics [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/):